# Adding Google Ads Event Snippet To Conversion Page (thank you.php)

Tags: php, woocommerce, google-ads-api

I have some google ads running on a Wordpress site running WooCommerce and I've added the global site tag to the header.php of my child theme which also has a google analytics tag, so the tag just looks like this in the header

```
<!-- global site tag (gtag.js) - google analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/YADDA YADDDA></script>
<script>
   window.datalayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   ...
   ...
   gtag('config', 'ANALYTICS TAG ID');
   gtag('config', 'AD TAG ID');
</script>
```

This all works good, but now I have to add the event snippet on the conversion page which for WooCommerce is the thankyou.php in the WooCommerce/templates/checkout/ folder I believe. Google specifies this to be placed in the header of that specific page. Should I be adding a function to my functions.php - of my child theme - that hooks into thankyou page and the header? or directly place it into the thankyou.php hook file - of child theme - to overwrite it? Then it is also asking to add code to dynamically pass a value to the transaction_id parameter and value and currency parameters. Event snippet below. I'm confused on how to do this and my last few attempts have ended with a site error.

```
<!-- Event snippet for DB_Purchase conversion page --> <script>
gtag('event', 'conversion', { 'send_to': 'AW-5555555/5555555', 'value': 45.0, 'currency': 'USD',
'transaction_id': ''}); </script>
```

placeholder tag used.

Comment: anyone know how to add this?

Comment: When you setup the script, you're gtag id is YADDA YADDA, does this correspond to the ANALYTICS TAG ID, or the AD TAG ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your child theme function.php at the end, and insert the proper tag.
``

```
<?php

function ds_checkout_analytics( $order_id ) {
   $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
   $currency = $order->get_order_currency();
   $total = $order->get_total();
   $date = $order->order_date;
?>
<!-- Paste Tracking Code Under Here -->


<!-- End Tracking Code -->
<?php   
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'ds_checkout_analytics' );
```

``